# Navigation and Tab Bar Controller not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier in the app delegate to show a view controller but for some reason the navigation bar and tab bar isn't show up. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - Thanks

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *view = (UINavigationController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShopViewController"];
self.window.rootViewController = view;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is ShopViewController a UINavigation controller or is it just a view controller. It sounds like you are declaring the view controller as uinavigationcontroller. 
Instead you should either drop a navigation controller on the storyboard and then give that an identifier OR you could just create a navigation controller in the app delegate.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ShopViewController *showViewController = (ShopViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShopViewController"];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:shopViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Comment: It worked but the the Tab Bar is missing (the Nav bar is shown)

Comment: because you also need to incorporate a tab bar controller, exactly the same way i suggested the navigation controller. I recommend you read through some WWDC videos about view controllers.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1
Have a look at the tutorial from Ray Wenderlich, he explains the different types.